# Not able to get autorestart to work in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am trying a spring-jersey sample project from spring boot samples github repo (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey). 
Server is not restarting after making changes to a java file. IDE= STS 3.8.0.RELEASE. I have seen tutorials where just mentioning below dependency worked for them. But its not working for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>           
</dependency>
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.bonzai</groupId>
<artifactId>boot</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Spring-Jersey-maven</name>
<description>DemoProject</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>           
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have run the application with different ways

1. mvn spring-boot:run from command line
2. run as java application
3. run as spring boot app

But none of them triggers a restart after java code change.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace with an exception?

Comment: should work just fine in case you modify a source file in STS and let STS compile to automatically to a .class file (automatic build enabled in STS). If that doesn't work, I would recommend to open a bug report at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and attach a sample project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Are you sure "Build automatically" is selected ?